# What does my discord bot mean by "Missing Permissions"

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I made a discord bot for reaction roles. I tried it on a testing server and it worked, but when I tried to put it in my original server this error pops up

```
Ignoring exception in on_raw_reaction_add
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\abdmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 312, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\abdmo\OneDrive\Desktop\Programming\(Folder)\Discord\Bot.py", line 55, in on_raw_reaction_add
    await member.add_roles(role)
  File "C:\Users\abdmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\member.py", line 641, in add_roles
    await req(guild_id, user_id, role.id, reason=reason)
  File "C:\Users\abdmo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 221, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chances are that you're trying to add a role that's above the bot's highest role. Moving the bot's highest role up the role hierarchy, so that the target role is below usually fixes this.